# Custom Adapter No Id Value

Tags: java, android

Hi im trying to populate a `listview` from a `baseadapter` and when selected on a `listview` the wrong `id` is propagated.

here is my adapter

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<Custom> AList;

    private LayoutInflater inflat;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Custom> results) {
        AList = results;
        inflat = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return AList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return AList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.suspect_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suspect_name);
            holder.txtSex = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suspect_sex);
            holder.txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suspect_id);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtName.setText(AList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtSex.setText(AList.get(position).getSex());
        holder.txtId.setText(AList.get(position).getID());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtSex;
        TextView txtId;
    }

}
```

Any Help you can provide would be great 
More code can be availble upon request

Answer (score 0):

Your getItemId() should return id.
So it should be like this->

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
        return AList.get(position).getID();
    }
```

Assuming that ID is long, if it is not then use -> `Long.parseLong(AList.get(position).getID());`

Comment: And it is showing wrong ID on UI right?

This thing not working-> 
`holder.txtId.setText(AList.get(position).getID());`
?

Comment: The rest of the fields populate correctly with data so this means that this is not the problem .. or am i mistaken

Comment: Check the contents of `AList` variable.
Observe what data you are getting in parameter `results`.
Might be something wrong with it only.